# Should it use realloc?

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

After looking at some open source projects C code I'm not sure if I'm doing stuff right.

When I'm creating strings (char *), I've normally done this:

```
#define DEF_LEN 10
char *mystring;
mystring = malloc(DEF_LEN*sizeof(char));
```

When I'm changing my string (normally done within a function):

```
mystring = realloc(mystring, strlen(newstring)*sizeof(char)+1);
strcpy(mystring,newstring);
```

On lots of open source projects I see that many dev's just do:

```
char another_string[1024];
```

Questions:

- Is my usage of `realloc` okay?
- Is `realloc` a performance killer (as used in my code / very often)?

Comment: `strlen(newstring)*sizeof(char)+1` should be `(strlen(newstring)+1)*sizeof(char)`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, perhaps even better, just omit `sizeof(char)` ? In any case where you put a multiplication with `1` doesn't matter much, no?

Comment: @Jens That would require the assumption that `sizeof(char)==1` which does not always hold. That said, I'm not sure as to which platforms it doesn't hold.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, the `sizeof` operator is defined as giving the size of a datatype in mutltiples of the size of `char`.

Comment: In C, sizeof(char) is always 1, so you don't need that multiplication. Just a point of information. Remember, too, that realloc (NULL, size) is equivalent to malloc(size). This is a  handy way to avoid an initial malloc( ) for a buffer that will be realloc'ed.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Qouth the ISO/IEC 9899 standard (C99 for short), point 6.5.3.4.2: When applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned char, or signed char,
(or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1.

Comment: @David Heffernan -- If sizeof(char) were not always 1, there would be no such thing as portable software.

Comment: well I always thought sizeof measured size in units of octet. Guess I was wrong. Thanks to everyone for educating me.

Comment: @David Heffernan
strlen(newstring)*sizeof(char)+1 this Statment is correct because is lenth of an char array is n than one index value is increased due to '\0'

Comment: @praveen Well I know that. But I thought sizeof measured in octets. That's the misunderstanding.

Comment: @David Heffernan
here in sizeof(char) size is not measured in octets it is measured in bytes

Comment: I think it is more correct to say you are creating "null-terminated C character arrays" or "C psuedo strings" or something along those lines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whoa there ...

```
mystring = realloc(mystring, strlen(newstring) * sizeof(char) + 1);
```

is a serious [**no-no** in C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malloc#Memory_leaks).  If `realloc` fails, then you have lost your ability to `free` `mystring` since you have overwritten it with `NULL`.

In terms of performance and reliability, I have always liked fixed length buffers on the stack.  It really does depend on your requirements.  If you have caps on your data sets, then using fixed length buffers is great.  You just have to be very careful not to overrun buffers and what not.  Then again, in C you always have to be concerned with `NUL` terminating buffers and making sure that you don't overrun them.

Comment: The memory allocators are often used for strings that must survive after the function completes. You pay a (small) cost in time for using `realloc()` (and later `free()`). If the string isn't needed after the function completes and you can determine a sensible size for it, then using a local variable is quicker, and the space is automatically released when the function completes — whereas you have to release (`free()`) explicitly allocated memory yourself — otherwise, you have an instance of the dreaded 'memory leak'. So, use local strings when you can; use allocated strings when you need to.